# How to separate string into 3 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a column of user names.

They are as follows:

```
'first       last      middleinitial'
```

Notice the large spaces between the name parts, ***these are always a different number of spaces***.

### Question:

How would I separate first, last, and middleinitial into *separate* columns (even if the spaces are different for every name)?

Comment: Do you have any spaced names ie Michael van den Avyle T.?

Comment: do you want to do this after receiving the result set or do you expect 3 columns in the result set?

Comment: are all name parts inside quotes?

Comment: no its just the names no quotes sorry.....and its always 3 part naming first last middle.

Comment: @user380432 you still haven't confirmed if there are spaces in any of the names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH t AS
(
    SELECT 'first       last      middleinitial' AS name
)

SELECT 
LEFT(name,CHARINDEX(' ', name)-1) 
,RIGHT(name, CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(name))-1)
,LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(name,CHARINDEX(' ', name),LEN(name)- CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(name))-CHARINDEX(' ', name))))
FROM t
```